# What is the size of Debian OS 8.6? & How to download it via torrent?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I want to download Debian 8.6 but when i see their website, there are actually 3 option of torrent file.

---

- debian-8.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.torrent  ~2 GB
- debian-8.6.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso.torrent  ~3 GB
- debian-8.6.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso.torrent  ~4 GB

---

*my architecture is amd64

Should I have to download it all ?
(A OS & 9-GB) 
Also, What is the Actual file size of debian 8.6 OS ? if you know then please tell me.
& if you know any torrent link that have full iso of it then please tell that too. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the DVD-1 file is required for installation. The DVD-2 and DVD-3 files contain additional packages that are only optional.

From [Debian's](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-dvd/) website:

> **There are lots of files here! Do I need all of them?**
>
> In most cases it is not necessary to download and use all of these
>   images to be able to install Debian on your computer. Debian comes
>   with a massive set of software packages, hence why it takes so many
>   disks for a complete set. Most typical users only need a small subset
>   of those software packages.
>
> Initially, you will only need to download and use the first image of a
>   set (labelled as debian-something-1 to be able to start the Debian
>   installer and set up Debian on your computer. If there are more images
>   available here (labelled debian-something-2, debian-something-3,
>   etc.), they contain the extra packages that can be installed on a
>   Debian system (as mentioned previously). They will not be bootable and
>   are entirely optional. If you have a fast Internet connection, you're
>   most likely better off installing any desired extra packages directly
>   from the Debian mirrors on the Internet instead of by using these
>   extra images.

The ISO file size for DVD-1 is listed as 3.7GB. The link for the torrent download is http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-dvd/debian-8.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.torrent

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as Accepted if this adequately addressed your question.

Comment: Forgot read the page. I'm such an idiot (it's just above that list.). **: )**

Answer (score 1):

You can save the bandwidth by downloading the debian CD `~ 630 M` , the torrent is available from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-cd/) : ([`debian-8.6.0-amd64-CD-1.iso.torrent`](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-cd/debian-8.6.0-amd64-CD-1.iso.torrent))

> Should I have to download it all ?

The same question has an answer on the frequently asked question : [Which of the numerous images should I download? **Do I need all of them?**](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#which-cd)

> No. First, of course you only need to download CD or DVD or BD images - the three types of images contain the same packages.
>
> in most cases it is not necessary to download all of the images for your architecture. The packages are sorted by popularity: The first CD/DVD/BD contains the installation system and the most popular packages. The second one contains slightly less popular ones, the third one even less popular ones, etc. You will probably only need the first couple of DVDs (or the first few CDs) unless you have very special requirements. (And in case you happen to need a package later on which is not on one of the CDs/DVDs/BDs you downloaded, you can always install that package directly from the Internet.)

Comment: I don't know how to  to accept multiple answer. but  I'm satisfied with your answer too.